# How can I change default file save locations?

Tags: interface

I would like to know if there is a simple way to have Blender (ver. 2.76b)save .blend files to a specified location by default. After install, my .blend files always saved to my \documents folder but as of sometime last week, I noticed them also ending up in appdata\local\microsoftwindows\temporaryinternetfiles\

I'd like to change this so that I have a dedicated Blender location, docs, pics, and so on. This answer [How do you change the default directory for saving/opening files?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29156/how-do-you-change-the-default-directory-for-saving-opening-files) says it can't, but I'm hoping something may have changed in the builds since that question was answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Head over to your User preferences here :

[image]

**Extra Tips:**
Or you could typically move the windows folder with "mklink" using windows
command prompt. Search google for makelink windows tutorial and you be really
powerful at managing your memory resources.